# 128 samples with node denoiser animation still flickering

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, shaders, keyframes, denoise

I'm trying to do an animation but even if  I doubled the samples my video is flickering, in another topic they suggest me to increase the samples, so I moved from 64 to 128 samples but the result is almost the same.
I'm using a denoiser node, someone told me to try to render without it and then use a video denoiser, but I found a lot of videos tutorial where they use it even with less samples and they don't have this flickering problem so I think there's something not setted correctly in my file, can someone check it or give some advices?

Here you can find the file wth the folder texture and the animation video folder:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ubn2ejn51cre75v/AACMnkRHLIz4jDkintteO-eYa?dl=0

Comment: All depends on the scene you're trying to render, TBH: 128 samples (the default) is not that much... try at least 500+ and find a good balance.

Comment: Did you checked my file for be sure that I didn't setted something wrong? Is it good?

Comment: Yep, had to disable the sequencer to render the first frame. Anyway, the issue is that your scene (at least frame 1) is an interior shot and *quite dark* which makes it pretty hard for cycles to resolve and the image is even noisy at **2000** samples, which I'd say is the minimum to render your scene properly, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFu87.png Also I'd suggest always render to an image sequence (preferably EXR) and compile it to a clip afterwards. Good news is that if that's the scene and nothing else is moving, you only have to render frame 150-222...

Comment: Explanation: [Blender Cycles Slow Rendering Interior Scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33145/blender-cycles-slow-rendering-interior-scene)

Comment: 2000?! ☹️ I’m already rendering an image sequence, and then esport the image strip in movie extension. Yes only

Comment: I checked and all my emission light have MIS activated... there are no other ways to fix that flickering? If I will use 2000+ samples it will be really fixed?

Comment: Is it bettere to have clamping setted or not? If yes which value is better?

Comment: As already mentioned by *susu* in the comments of your other question -> one reason for the flickering is a low sample count. In addition to that, your scene is quite dark and you are using geometry lights which slows down the rendering as well. Again, all depends on your scene, just test it, there is no recipe how to render a scene properly. I'd suggest render 5 frames at 2000 samples and see whether the flickering is gone... and I personally would avoid clamping any values, makes it unrealistic. If this is a hobby project, consider using a farm like https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/

Answer (score 1):

I played with light bounces, clamping, filter glossy and caustics settings and I tried to set it to the min possible value without loosing too many details; this have reduced a little bit the noise but still looked so bad.

[image]

Then I found a tutorial on youtube, so I removed the neons objects with emission shader and replace it with area lights, with this I've almost removed all the noise

[image]

Then I tried to switch from Path Tracing integrator sampling to the Branched Path Tracing and this completly removed almost all noise but increase a lot time render (from 3.00min to 15.00min)

[image]

So I tried to decrease the samples number (from 128 to 32) to decrease the time rendering, this added more noise but still look good

[image]

Now I will play with settings to adjust it more and increase details and then try to add a denoise node.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Flicker Free Denoising** this add-on is great a denoising animations without flicker even at very low sample rates. I've got 10-15 samples to work great!

Try it here: https://4917137779526.gumroad.com/l/FlickerFreeDenoising
[image]