# Shadow only plane isn't working. Keeps sending me the ground as being pitch black, and I have compared it to a working file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have tried copying the settings from (http://rgbmix.blogspot.com/2014/08/shadow-only-material-in-cycles.html) To no evail. Here is my .blend (http://1drv.ms/1GO6f2F)

Comment: do you have any lights on the scene?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/why-does-the-shadow-pass-not-account-for-mesh-lights and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28491/does-an-hdr-environment-texture-affect-the-shadow-pass

Comment: I realised that these methods I have tried to create a shadow only plane do not, for some reason, work with HDRI's I'll post a new question with the HDRi/Shadow only plane problem EDIT: I found the answer to that too

Comment: Could you post the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Any questions on this solution I came up with, just ask. Sorry for the late reply. Hope this helps the rest of you! You can use an HDRI with this BTW!